# Rails model with two foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a model for Items and a model for Offers. The idea is that an Item can have many offers from other items (e.g. Item 1 has an offer from Item 2). The only thing the Offer model holds is the item_id, in this case 1 and the offered_item_id in this case 2. I can't seem to get the associations correctly.

What I'm aiming to do is return a list with the user's items and the information of the items offered for trade for each one. So far I have:

```
    "item_id": "2",
    "item_name":"test",    
    "offers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "item_id": 2,
            **"offered_item_id": 3**
        }]
```

On top of the offer details I want to show the information of item_id = 3. How can I achieve this?

Item Model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :offers, :class_name => 'Offer', :foreign_key => :item_id
  has_many :offers_as_offered, :class_name => 'Offer', :foreign_key => :offered_item_id
end
```

Offer Model

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :item, :class_name => "Item"
 belongs_to :offered_item, :class_name => "Item"
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "items", force: true do |t|
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.string   "brand"
 t.string   "item_type"
end


 create_table "offers", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "offered_item_id"
 end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your model and migration files as well please?

Comment: I updated the original post with the models and the schema.